# Advice Ad-Blocking+DNS over TLS+Hiding IP on LAN with Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking

In order to prevent to block adds and prevent my ISP from knowing the sites I visit for all the devices in my local network (two desktops & a raspberry connected to the modem-router via wire + a laptop & cell phones via Wi-Fi) I installed pi-hole +unbound on another Raspberry which I connected to the router via Ethernet.

So to be able to change the DNS server in my modem-router (so that the DNS server is my Raspberry) my ISP has to take me out of CG NAT, and said ISP tells me it's less safe since my router will have a uniquely identifiable IP.

I'm trying now to also hide my IP, routing all my traffic through the Tor network. I've only found tutorials on how to do it for a wireless hotspot. My question is two fold:

- Any pointers on how to make wired an wireless traffic go through Tor network with a Raspberry?
- Would it be possible to have pie-hole+unbound in the Raspberry used to connect to the Tor network? Or I wouldn't need DNS over TLS any more?

DISCLAIMER: As it may be obvious, I'm a complete ignorant in anything networking, so feel free to correct any conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I don't use Privoxy, so [take this answer with a grain of salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grain_of_salt):

You may wish to look at the ["Privoxy" project](https://www.privoxy.org/); actually, you should probably [start at the Privoxy Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privoxy) as it seems more informative. If you'll expend a little effort on Google, you'll find a lot of "help" in setting up the `privoxy` configuration file.

Ordinarily, I wouldn't propose an answer using something I have no experience with, but I made an exception for two reasons:

1. You've indicated you are "ignorant in anything networking", and
2. `privoxy` is an available package in RPi's apt repository, so it's easy to install, easy to remove, and easy to maintain ("easy" being a relative term of course :)

You can install as follows:

`sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get upgrade 
 sudo apt-get install privoxy`

In addition to `man privoxy` (which you should read after installing), the [Debian project's wiki has some information](https://wiki.debian.org/FreedomBox/Manual/Privoxy) that looks to be quite useful... you should probably read it, and the [FAQ](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/index.html) that's referenced. There seems to be all sorts of useful links here that might help.

BEFORE YOU START: I noticed that RPi's apt repository also has a package called `freedombox-privoxy`. This ***might*** be a better choice; I'll leave you to sort that one, but here's some [background on "FreedomBox" from Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreedomBox) And here's the [FreedomBox home page](https://freedomboxfoundation.org/news/freedombox-privoxy/)

If you decide to go this way, you'd install it exactly as above, except replace `privoxy` with `freedombox-privoxy`

Good luck.